# Xcode: I added a build configuration to by app, and it won't build, unless I also add a same named build configuration to the framework

Tags: ios, xcode, xcframework

In Xcode, I have an iOS app with a framework (the framework is used to house the code that is common to multiple app targets like watch app or widget extension), and the framework uses SwiftProtobuf package.

I duplicated the "Debug" configuration of the main app target as "Debug (Pro)" (adding a custom compilation condition that I can use to easily test the app with unlocked in-app purchases), and now building the project fails (as the frameworks fails to build, as it's missing the SwiftProtobuf).

[image]

[image]

When I added the "Debug (Pro)" configuration to the framework as well, the app started to build successfully again.

Why is that? Can I keep multiple configurations like `Debug (Pro)` for the app without having to duplicate them for the framework? If so, do I need to somehow tell the Xcode to reuse framework's Debug configuration for app's `Debug (Pro)` configuration.